# Converting large parquet files to csv in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working on the parquets to csv conversion through AWS. i'm able to convert the files using Lambda, but the scenario is a bit different while working with more than 1GB files. Can anyone suggest how I can convert the large parquets to CSV's.

1. The parquets are stored in s3 and csv should be stored back to CSV's.

Thanks,
Samhith G

Comment: Setup a job in glue for that?

Comment: @Marcin, I've scheduled a job, but every time I'll be getting different parquet file schemas.